# What was the first picaresque novel in Portuguese literature?

Tags: history-of-literature, portuguese-language

The first [picaresque novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picaresque_novel) in European literature was the Spanish novel *Lazarillo de Tormes*, which was first published in 1554. The Wikipedia article about the genre does not mention any examples in Portuguese even though both countries share a long border and use languages belonging to the same language family. I would assume that there was some form of cultural exchange between Spain and Portugal. For example, the Portuguese historian and poet [Manuel de Faria e Sousa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manuel_de_Faria_e_Sousa) (1590–1649; previously mentioned in a [question about the *Lusiads*](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/18015/2191)) frequently wrote in Spanish.

The [Portuguese Wikipedia article about the picaresque novel](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romance_picaresco) does not seem to mention any Portuguese examples of the genre. Did the editors of that article overlook Portuguese examples or were Portuguese authors never interested in the genre?